# PHP if condition double value checking in single condition without OR or AND

Tags: php, zend-framework, if-statement

this question will feel silly and very basic, but i dont know why it occures and why php is not supporting it :( . So please ignore my idiotic statements in this question.

While working in ZF, i need to check an age variable with selected criteria for age ranges. I use Zend Studio as IDE. So when i placed if conditions like below:

```
if(20 <= $userAge <= 30) {...}
```

I then changed my conditions like below, which works fine:

```
if($userAge >= 20 AND $userAge <= 30) {...}
```

Zend studio did not created a syntax errors and everything seems fine, but when i reloaded my page , i got a php error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<=' (T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/othaim-jobs/application/modules/search/models/Search.php on line 240
```

As i remember such kind of if statements are allowed in some other languages (i think c / c++, not sure about others).

I hope i will get a nice response.

Thanks to all.

Comment: you need to read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @Mahan, i have more than 4 years experience in php :) ,

Comment: thank you =) well I just really don't know that is possible to make an argument like this `20 <= $userAge <= 30` usually what I know is `20 <= $userAge && $userAge <= 30`.. sorry about that.. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
if(20 <= $userAge <= 30) {...}
```

why dont you use simple approach

```
if( $userAge>= 20 &&  $userAge <=30)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your example like this

```
<?php

$userage=21;
if($userage >= 20 && $userage <= 30)
{
 echo "Yes you are in this category !"; //prints since 21 ranges between 20 and 30
}
```

Comment: kindly check updated question, i need to know the reason why it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

To check age between 20 and 30, Condition should be

```
if($userAge >=20 and $userAge<=30)
```

Comment: u were 10 seconds faster than me :)

Comment: @RishabhRaj may be :-)

Comment: There is no error in updated if condition. may be cache issues?